# Data comes only on 2nd click (with delay and wrong)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

Im new in Angular and I need your help
im trying to make a parent elemnt controlling the codntiion of visiobility of popUp in child component
Im trying to get the data from Parent element in Child element 
Im pushing div on click with own PoPup , and each div has own PoPup and own status isVisible: true or false and index

Ive tried to use async/await methods to wait data in Child component

Here is a child component.ts

```
export class Child implements OnInit {
  @Input() index;
  @Input() objectForChild;
  @Output() sayHi = new EventEmitter();
  public currentVisibility: boolean = false;

  ngOnInit() {
}
  public async showHiddenBtn(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.objectForChild = this.currentVisibility
    await console.log(this.objectForChild); // f.e I push 1st div , I want to see 
{index: 0, isVisible: true} but it shows undefined when I make 2nd click on 2nd div 
I want to see {index: 1, isVisible: true} but it shows {index: 0, isVisible: true}.
  }

}
```

Here is code from Parent.ts

```
 public objectForChild; // this variable is passing to child component

  ngOnInit() {
   this.copyFavouriteList = favoriteList.favorites.filter(favorite => favorite.type === 'payment');
      let i;
      for (i = 0 ; i < this.copyFavouriteList.length ; i++){
        let obj = {
          'index': i,
          'isVisible': false
        };
        this.copyOfArr.push(obj);
      }
    })
  }

  async takeEmit(index){
    let foundArray =  this.copyOfArr.filter(elem => {
      return elem.index === index
    });
    if(foundArray){
      foundArray[0].isVisible = !foundArray[0].isVisible;
    }
    this.objectForChild = await {...foundArray[0]};
    console.log(this.objectForChild); // shows the correct data 
{index: 0, isVisible: true} at moment of the click
  }
```

Here is Parent.html:

```
<parent *ngFor="let favorite of favoriteList; let i = index">
 ...
  <child [index]="i" (sayHi)="takeEmit($event)" 
  [objectForChild]="objectForChild">
                  </child>
            </div>
<parent />
```

I expect to receive for each child element correct data from parent
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: So delete this question if its no longer an issue.

Comment: thanks this question is no longer an issue